# EF Core - IgnoreQueryFilters для навигационной проперти

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Нужно отменить применение фильтра у нав-проперти в конкретном запросе, примерно так:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SecondaryEntity>().HasQueryFilter(d => d.Bar == true);
...
var foo = Db.MainEntity
             .Include(x => x.SecondaryEntity.IgnoreQueryFilters());
```

Как это можно реализовать? Штатно это не работает, как я понимаю (но в документации тоже не нашёл про это ничего).

Comment: `blogs = db.Blogs
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList();`  [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Comment: @tym32167 это отменит фильтр для Blogs, но не для Posts, разве нет?

Comment: Не попробуете - не узнаете. Я то просто ваш вопрос загуглил.

Comment: @tym32167 я был уверен, что это только для сущности верхнего уровня. Даже пытался вам это написать, но решил перепроверить чтоб не попасть ногами в жир :) Это работает, внешне для меня это не работало, потому что был `left join`. Посмотрел как ef построил итоговые запросы и всё стало ясно. Спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо, что сработало. Думаю, будет полезно если напишете ответ.